# AlertDialog looks weird on Android/Mono

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I am using this code to display an AlertDialog on a network error:

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetMessage(error);

builder.SetCancelable(false);
builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
builder.Show();
```

However, it looks like this:

[image]

**Problems:**

1. The current view is not displayed behind the alertdialog, it's just white.
2. It aligned to the top, not center
3. The theme or font color is wrong making the text hard to read.

I am using Theme.DeviceDefault.Light as theme for the activity:

```
[Activity (Label = "xxx", Theme = "@style/MyAppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
```

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
   </style>
</resources>
```

How to fix this? Have tried to insert MyAppTheme as second argument to `AlertDialog.Builder(this, Resource.Style.MyAppTheme)` but with no change in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Used

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, Android.App.AlertDialog.ThemeHoloLight);
```

and it looks better. I also used Activity.ShowDialog() and placed my AlertDialog code inside

```
protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args)
```

not sure that it did any difference.

Good blogpost: http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html